# TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando criar um código para em um determinado canal quando uma mensagem é identificada, duas Emojis são adicionados imediatamente naquela mensagem, mas nas mensagens daquele canal especifico.

Já tentei varias maneiras, como criando variáveis pra tentar distorcer e mudar mas sempre da a mesma coisa.

```
let canal = client.channels.get("603948500765507598")
if (canal.message.content === '') {
    message.react('');
    message.react('');
}
```

Comment: Qual é o valor de `canal`? Veja através do console ou ferramentas de debug.

Comment: `client.channels.get("603948500765507598")` está retornando `undefined`, verifique se esse número está correto, pode ser isso. Que api/biblioteca/framework está usando?

Comment: Também achei que era isso, porém já tentei trocar com outro canal e pegar o id, e deu na mesma, eu uso node.js/discord.js

Comment: E qual é o retorno da função `get` conforme a documentação?

Comment: Não sei ao certo, sobre `get` o console não da retorno, se caso tenha algo relacionado na documentação eu não estou sabendo, ainda sou "iniciante" nessa area.